# ng2-dragula after adding new item it's getting displayed at the top

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, dragula, ng2-dragula

I am using ng2-dragula for drag and drop feature. I am seeing issue when I drag and drop first element(or any element) at the end and then try to add new item to the array using addNewItem button, new item is not getting added to the end. If i don't drop element to the end, new item is getting added at the end in UI.
I want new items to be displayed at the bottom in any scenario. Any help is appreciated.
This issue is not reproducible with Angular 7. I see this happening with Angular 9

**JS**

```
export class SampleComponent {

  items = ['Candlestick','Dagger','Revolver','Rope','Pipe','Wrench'];
  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) { 
    dragulaService.createGroup("bag-items", {
      removeOnSpill: false
    });
  }

  public addNewItem() {
    this.items.push('New Item');
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" [dragula]='"bag-items"' [(dragulaModel)]='items'>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</div> 
</div>
```

<button id="addNewItem" (click)="addNewItem()">Add New Item

[image]

I edited the stackblitz from the comment to help visualize the issue. This seems to be triggered when a unit is dragged to the bottom of the list. Updated stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-ykm8fz?file=src/app/app.component.html
[ItemsAddedOutOfOrder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERvqH.png)

Comment: Instead of doing items.push(). Try doing items.unshift().

Comment: @Muhammad Kamran - Tried using unshift, result is same. Infact with this change items are getting added always at the top. Before it was getting added only when we drag any element to the end

Comment: Can you please reproduce it here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-9g85jk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @yurzui - I am not able to reproduce in stackblitz url shared. But locally I am able to reproduce with angular 9

Comment: That's hard to help you if you can't reproduce it.

Comment: @yurzui I tried locally with same dependency versions used in stackblitz, except @angular/cli. I had to use 10.0.7 as 9.1.1 is not compatible. I am still seeing the issue. But with angular version 7.2.0 I see it working as expected. There is open issue for similar problem in GitHub - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/975.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to restore old item position on drop.

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
  this.subscription = this.dragulaService.drop().subscribe(({ name }) => {
    this.dragulaService.find(name).drake.cancel(true);
  });
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-base-s9fvqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

### Explanation

There is some difference between how Ivy and ViewEngine insert ViewRef at specific index. They relay on different beforeNode

Ivy always returns ViewContainer host(Comment node)<sup>[ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/core/src/view/view_attach.ts#L124)</sup> if we add item to the end:

```
export function getBeforeNodeForView(viewIndexInContainer: number, lContainer: LContainer): RNode|
    null {
  const nextViewIndex = CONTAINER_HEADER_OFFSET + viewIndexInContainer + 1;
  if (nextViewIndex < lContainer.length) {
    const lView = lContainer[nextViewIndex] as LView;
    const firstTNodeOfView = lView[TVIEW].firstChild;
    if (firstTNodeOfView !== null) {
      return getFirstNativeNode(lView, firstTNodeOfView);
    }
  }

  return lContainer[NATIVE]; <============================= this one
}
```

ViewEngine returns last rendered node(last `<li/>` element)<sup>[ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b071495f9216324783a8c4daca077acf9850292e/packages/core/src/render3/node_manipulation.ts#L730)</sup>

```
function renderAttachEmbeddedView(
    elementData: ElementData, prevView: ViewData|null, view: ViewData) {
  const prevRenderNode =
      prevView ? renderNode(prevView, prevView.def.lastRenderRootNode!) : elementData.renderElement;
  ...
}
```

The solution might be reverting the dragged element back to original container so that we can let built-in `ngForOf` Angular directive to do its smart diffing.

Btw, the same technique is used in Angular material `DragDropModule`. It remembers position of dragging element and after we drop item it inserts it at its old position in the DOM which is IMPORTANT.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.This has helped me a lot.  I see items getting added at the end of the list.